# Transpose after separating only the variable name

Tags: r, transpose

I'm a newbie in R, but I am addicted to mastering! I'm working on a project for work and I'm completely stumped!  Any help is much appreciated!

I need to convert this data frame...

```
   Brand       UK__Sales__YA   UK__Sales__MAT  CN__Sales__YA  CN__Sales__MAT
1  Snickers    100             110            90             95
2  Twix        50              60             30             35
3  Skittles    75              80             105            130
```

... to this one

```
   Brand       Country     Year      Sales
1  Snickers    UK          YA        100
2  Snickers    UK          MAT       110
3  Snickers    CN          YA        90
4  Snickers    CN          MAT       95
5  Twix        UK          YA        50
6  Twix        UK          MAT       60
7  Twix        CN          YA        30
8  Twix        CN          MAT       35
9  Skittles    UK          YA        75
10 Skittles    UK          MAT       80
11 Skittles    CN          YA        105
12 Skittles    CN          MAT       130
```

As you can tell, I need break off the first part & last part of my Sales variables and create them as separate stacks of data.  I have additional countries & additional metrics in the my dataset, but I think if you can help me solve this, then I can finish it up.  Thanks!! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) dplyr/tidyr** Using the data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end gather the data frame from wide to long form and then separate out the pieces of the new column.  Spread the new Variable column into Price and Sales using the Value column as the values in them and then sort. The last line of code could be omitted if the order does not matter.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF %>% 
  gather(new, Value, -Brand) %>%
  separate(new, c("Country", "Variable", "Year"), sep = "__") %>%
  spread(Variable, Value) %>%
  arrange(Brand, desc(Country), desc(Year))
```

giving:

```
      Brand Country Year Sales
1  Skittles      UK   YA    75
2  Skittles      UK  MAT    80
3  Skittles      CN   YA   105
4  Skittles      CN  MAT   130
5  Snickers      UK   YA   100
6  Snickers      UK  MAT   110
7  Snickers      CN   YA    90
8  Snickers      CN  MAT    95
9      Twix      UK   YA    50
10     Twix      UK  MAT    60
11     Twix      CN   YA    30
12     Twix      CN  MAT    35
```

Note that the above also works `DF2` also defined in the Note below.

**1a)** This slightly shorter alternative would also work but only with `DF`, not with `DF2`.  Again the `arrange` line could be omitted if the order does not matter.

```
DF %>% 
  gather(new, Sales, -Brand) %>%
  separate(new, c("Country", "Year"), sep = "__Sales__") %>%
  arrange(Brand, desc(Country), desc(Year))
```

**2)** This alternative involves no packages using `reshape` to reshape from wide to long form.  If the row names and order do not matter everything from the `rownames(long) <- NULL` statement onwards could be omitted.  This code also works with `DF2`.

```
varying <- split(names(DF)[-1], sub(".*__(.*)__.*", "\\1", names(DF)[-1]))
long <- reshape(DF, dir = "long", idvar = "Brand", varying = varying, 
   v.names = names(varying))
out <- transform(long, Country = sub("__.*", "", time), Year = sub(".*__", "", time), 
   time = NULL)
rownames(out) <- NULL
o <- with(out, order(Brand, -xtfrm(Country), -xtfrm(Year)))
out <- out[o, ]
out
```

giving:

```
      Brand Sales Country Year
3  Skittles    75      UK   YA
6  Skittles    80      UK  MAT
9  Skittles   105      CN   YA
12 Skittles   130      CN  MAT
1  Snickers   100      UK   YA
4  Snickers   110      UK  MAT
7  Snickers    90      CN   YA
10 Snickers    95      CN  MAT
2      Twix    50      UK   YA
5      Twix    60      UK  MAT
8      Twix    30      CN   YA
11     Twix    35      CN  MAT
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "   Brand       UK__Sales__YA   UK__Sales__MAT  CN__Sales__YA  CN__Sales__MAT
1  Snickers    100             110            90             95
2  Twix        50              60             30             35
3  Skittles    75              80             105            130"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines)

# same as DF but with additional columns for Price
DF2 <- cbind(DF, setNames(10 * DF[2:5], sub("Sales", "Price", names(DF)[2:5])))
```

Comment: Thank you, Grothendieck!  And Jason, Rui, and Akrun!

Comment: A follow-up question:  If I have metrics in addition to __Sales__ (such as __Price__), is there an efficient way to include this into the dplyr/tidyr code?  My current method, of creating separate data frames with select variables, then merging, feels cumbersome.  Make sense?

Comment: Have defined `DF2` in the Note at the end and modified (1) and (2), but not (1a) to handle both.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [`tidyr`](https://blog.rstudio.com/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/) package -- in fact, all of the packages in the [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/) are helpful for this type of data munging work:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  gather(key, Sales, -Brand) %>%
  separate(key, c("Country", "delete", "Year"), sep = "__") %>%
  select(-delete) %>%
  arrange(Brand)

#       Brand Country Year Sales
# 1  Skittles      UK   YA    75
# 2  Skittles      UK  MAT    80
# 3  Skittles      CN   YA   105
# 4  Skittles      CN  MAT   130
# 5  Snickers      UK   YA   100
# 6  Snickers      UK  MAT   110
# 7  Snickers      CN   YA    90
# 8  Snickers      CN  MAT    95
# 9      Twix      UK   YA    50
# 10     Twix      UK  MAT    60
# 11     Twix      CN   YA    30
# 12     Twix      CN  MAT    35
```

To understand what's going on, run each pipe `%>%` statement individually: (e.g. look at the output after `df %>% gather(key, Sales, -Brand)` to see what that does). Next run the transformations through the `separate` pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`.  We `gather` into 'long' format and then `extract` the 'Var' column into 'Country' and 'Year'

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
gather(df1, Var, Sales, -Brand) %>%
    extract(Var, into = c("Country", "Year"), "(\\w+)__\\w+__(\\w+)")
#      Brand Country Year Sales
#1  Snickers      UK   YA   100
#2      Twix      UK   YA    50
#3  Skittles      UK   YA    75
#4  Snickers      UK  MAT   110
#5      Twix      UK  MAT    60
#6  Skittles      UK  MAT    80
#7  Snickers      CN   YA    90
#8      Twix      CN   YA    30
#9  Skittles      CN   YA   105
#10 Snickers      CN  MAT    95
#11     Twix      CN  MAT    35
#12 Skittles      CN  MAT   130
```

---

A corresponding option with `data.table` would be

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df1), id.var = "Brand", value.names = "Sales")[, 
 c("Country", "Year") := tstrsplit(variable, "__")[-2]][, variable := NULL][]
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is a solution using package `reshape2`.

```
new <- reshape2::melt(data, id.vars = "Brand")
new$Country <- sub("(^[^_]*)_.*$", "\\1", new$variable)
new$Year <- sub("^.*_([[:alpha:]]*$)", "\\1", new$variable)
new <- new[, c(1, 4, 5, 3)]
names(new)[4] <- "Sales"

head(new)
#     Brand Country Year Sales
#1 Snickers      UK   YA   100
#2     Twix      UK   YA    50
#3 Skittles      UK   YA    75
#4 Snickers      UK  MAT   110
#5     Twix      UK  MAT    60
#6 Skittles      UK  MAT    80
```

**DATA**

```
data <-
structure(list(Brand = c("Snickers", "Twix", "Skittles"), UK__Sales__YA = c(100L, 
50L, 75L), UK__Sales__MAT = c(110L, 60L, 80L), CN__Sales__YA = c(90L, 
30L, 105L), CN__Sales__MAT = c(95L, 35L, 130L)), .Names = c("Brand", 
"UK__Sales__YA", "UK__Sales__MAT", "CN__Sales__YA", "CN__Sales__MAT"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```